# How many rectangles are here?

Tags: geometry

[image]

My friend says there are 112. I want to make sure I am correct

The half by half: 8

The half by 1: 8

The 1 by 1: 18

The 1 by 2: 24

The 1 by 3: 16

The 1 by 4: 8

The 2 by 2: 9

The 2 by 3: 12

The 3 by 3: 4

The 4 by 3: 4

The 4 by 4: 1

Total 112

I just want to make sure if my answer is correct.

Also I would like to see a systematic way of doing this

Look at remaining degree of freedom. The degree of freedom is 4+1-width or height. Multiply degree of freedom to get numbers of rectangles with the same size.

If height is not the same with width, multiply by 2 because we have another version rotated 90 degree. Voila. We got them.

So, a 4 by 3 triangles will have 1 and 2 degree of freedom. Width differs from height. So 1*2*2=4 rectangles.

Am I correct?

Are there more systematic way to compute this?

Comment: I agree with 112.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a grid of $n\times m$ lines, there are ${n\choose 2}{m\choose 2}$ rectangles as we can pick the two vertical and horizontal lines that bound the rectangle.

Thus within each of the "extra" squares, we have ${3\choose 2}^2=9$ rectangles; and within the major square grid, we have ${5\choose 2}^2=100$ rectangles. We neither double-counted nor have other options, hence the answer is
$$ 100+2\cdot 9=118.$$

*Remark:* It seems you left out $2\times 4$.